# All inputs and dropdown should be blocked (no possibility to write or select options) until you press the Edit button. Why is it not working?

Tags: angular, edit, angular-ngselect

My html file:

```
<div class="main-wrapper" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
<mat-card class="box">
    <mat-card-header>
        <mat-card-title>Register</mat-card-title>
    </mat-card-header>

    <form [formGroup]="registerForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" novalidate>

        <!-- Username -->
        <mat-card-content>
            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                <input matInput placeholder="Username" ngModel name="username" minlength="5"
                    formControlName="username" required [readOnly]="!enableEdit">
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-error *ngIf="username.touched && !username.valid">
                <div *ngIf="username.errors.required">Username is required.</div>
                <div *ngIf="username.errors.minlength">Username should be minimum 5 characters.</div>
            </mat-error>

            <!-- Email -->
            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                <input matInput placeholder="Email" ngModel name="email" minlength="5" [pattern]="emailPattern"
                    formControlName="email" required [readOnly]="!enableEdit">
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-error *ngIf="email.touched && !email.valid">
                <div *ngIf="email.errors.required">Email is required.</div>
                <div *ngIf="email.errors.pattern">Email is not valid.</div>
            </mat-error>

            <!-- Password -->
            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                <input matInput placeholder="Password" ngModel name="password" minlength="5"
                    formControlName="password" required [readOnly]="!enableEdit">
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-error *ngIf="password.touched && !password.valid">
                <div *ngIf="password.errors.required">Password is required.</div>
                <div *ngIf="password.errors.minlength">Password should be minimum 5 characters.</div>
            </mat-error>

            <!-- Repeat Password -->
            <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
                <input matInput placeholder="Confirm Password" ngModel name="confirmpassword" formControlName="confirmpassword"
                    required [readOnly]="!enableEdit">
            </mat-form-field>
            <mat-error *ngIf="confirmpassword.touched && confirmpassword.value != password.value"> Passwords does not match
            </mat-error>

            <ng-select [items]="items" bindLabel="name" ngModel name="dropdown" formControlName="dropdown" required [disabled]="!enableEdit"></ng-select>
            <div *ngIf="!dropdown" class="invalid-feedback">Dropdown is required</div>

        </mat-card-content>

        <button mat-button color="primary" class="btn-block" (click)="enableEdit = !enableEdit">Edit</button>
        <button mat-button color="primary" class="btn-block" type="submit" [disabled]="!registerForm.valid">Register</button>
    
    </form>
</mat-card>
```

My ts file:

```
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register-form',
  templateUrl: './register-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register-form.component.css']
})
export class RegisterFormComponent implements OnInit {

  emailPattern = "^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$";  //Pattern to check if email is correct
  
  registerForm;

  enabledEdit = false;


  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  
  ngOnInit() {
    this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      username: [''],
      email: [''],
      password: [''],
      confirmpassword: [''],
      dropdown:['']
    });
  } 

  items = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Option 1'
    }, 
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Option 2'
    }, {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Option 3'
    }, {
      id: 4,
      name: 'Option 4'
    },
  ]

 

  get username() {
    return this.registerForm.get('username');
  }
  get email() {
    return this.registerForm.get('email');
  }
  get password() {
    return this.registerForm.get('password');
  }
  get confirmpassword() {
    return this.registerForm.get('confirmpassword');
  }
  get dropdown() {
    return this.registerForm.get('dropdown');
  }


  onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.registerForm.value)
  }
}
```

All inputs and dropdown should be blocked (no possibility to write or select options) until you press the Edit button.

> Why is it not working?

How to do it, there was only an Edit button which turns into my Register button when pressed?

Comment: thre're nothink like `ng-disabled` in Angular. As you're using material, you can use the property `readOnly` `[readOnly]="!enableEdit" in input and `[disabled]="!enableEdit"` in mat-select. You can also use `[attr.disabled]="!enabledEdit?'true':null` or disable the formControl

Comment: I've added [readOnly]="!enableEdit" in inputs and [disabled]="!enableEdit" in ng-select but it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when declaring your forms set the disabled attribute there like this :

```
 this.disableForm = true;
 this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
   username:[{value:'', disabled:this.disableForm}],
   ...
})
```

and then on user click bind your click event to function instead of change directly.

```
enableEdit(){
    //change monitoring status for the form
    this.disableForm = !this.disableForm;
    // if form is enabled then disable it. else enable the form
    if(!this.disableForm) this.registerForm.disable();
    else this.registerForm.enable();
}
```

Some remarks on the code if it could help:

- you are using combination of reactive forms and template driven form on a single form. this is bad practice and may lead to form unpredictable behaviors.
- try to initialize the form on the `constructor` instead of `OnInit`.
- give edit button a `type="button"` default is submit

Comment: It works, thank you! How to do, there was only an Edit button which turns into my Register button when pressed?

Comment: your edit button type was submit so it post the form. just add type attribute for it

Comment: I have no idea how. I've tried to do it but it's not working. Could you help me?